Pipe keyboard shortcut and highlighting with mouse doesn't work when knitting to a PDF in R Markdown
I'm writing a paper and knitting to a PDF in R Markdown. Everything is going fine (the document knits, including with pasted code from a different document that includes pipes), but I can't use the keyboard shortcut to pipe, and I can't highlight text with my mouse. Both work fine if I'm knitting to html, but just doesn't respond in PDF. I've checked all the shortcut settings and other issues that people have described when keyboard shortcuts don't work, but no issues there. Has anyone else run into this issue?

What version of R, RStudio, and knitr are you using?
